# Can I carry someone's homeopathy medicine along to Dublin?

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, london, drugs, dublin

I will soon be traveling to Dublin from India visa London. And I have been asked to carry some homeopathy medicine for a friend.
The medicine is from Soukya and have a bill and signed letter from physician stating

" This parcel contains non prescription medicine which comes under natural herbal supplement and are for personal use only"

The prescription/letter and bill contain my friend's name.

Homeopathy medicine are at time sugar pills with some liquid coating. (I haven't opened all of the packets).

Is it fine if I carry these or there can be some issues?

This is my first time traveling to Dublin that too via London so I'm uncertain about this.

Comment: How well do you know the friend?  How sure are you that the pills are really what you are told they are?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your responses. I have my flight tomorrow and I've decided I'll not be taking these along with me as it's not mine and there's no way for me to find out what the actual ingredients are. Primary reason is the parcel as I was told recently is not my friend's but a friend's friend. So I'm not taking it.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151371/discussion-on-question-by-im-that-guy-can-i-carry-someones-homeopathy-medicine); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: If you want to keep everybody happy, replace those pills with [tictacs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic_Tac). Whatever your friend's ailment, they will work just as effectively as any homeopathic remedy. And you won't end up spending five years in jail if the pills turn out not to be so homeopathic as you thought.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I would advise against taking any objects given to you by someone else for someone else. Homeopathic medicine is readily available in Ireland. The letter signed by a physician sounds fishy, since homeopathy is a pseudoscience, meaning that licensed physicians cannot officially recommend it to their patients and are unlikely to write letters certifying homeopathic medications for international travel (I admit things could be different in India).

Comment: @Willeke herbal medicine is not the same as homeopathic medicine. Using lemon and honey to fight flu is normal and a doctor would recommend it. Using oscilococcinum is foolish.

Comment: @brhans My understanding is that in some areas of the world (and with some individuals found everywhere) 'homeopathic' is a synonym for 'alternative medicine'.  That is, not everyone is aware of the precise definition of homeopathy.  I've even picked up a little booklet on this from a homeopathy display that correctly explains homeopathy and then lists arnica cream as a homeopathic remedy.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151364/discussion-on-answer-by-johnnyjanko-can-i-carry-someones-homeopathy-medicine-al); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: I have left one comment even though it was not highly upvoted because it explains cultural differences which can be important in cases like this.

Answer (score 49):

**Be careful!**

- Where did you obtain the sugar pills?  Did you get them yourselves from the pharmacy, or were they given to you by someone?  If you got them from a pharmacy, did it look like a normal pharmacy or is there any chance that there is something fishy going on?  Are they in a usual package (factory-sealed, professional labelling) or does it look unprofessional?
- How well do you know the friend in Ireland?  Is this someone you know and trust personally, or is it a "friend" you know on the internet?

If you're not absolutely 100.00% sure that those pills are what you are told they are, I would strongly recommend not to take them.  You risk consequences that are **much** worse than confiscated property or deportation.  You don't want to risk being a foolish accidental drug mule!

Comment: There's no way someone in this position could be absolutely 100% sure.  It may be, however, that if the pills are found to contain e.g. illegal narcotics, but this is contrary to their labeling and they appear not to have been tampered with, that a prosecution for drug smuggling would fail.  Or maybe not -- I know nothing about the elements of such crimes in Irish law.  But certainly if the pills are _not_ factory sealed, if the "friend" is an acquaintance, or if there are any other red or even yellow flags, the prudent course of action is to refuse to participate.

Comment: @phoog Sure, possibly the prosecution would fail, but even so, being held in pre-trial custody for several weeks or even just a couple of days only to be released without charge is probably not what OP plans for their Dublin trip (I have no clue how this is handled in Ireland either, and I assume the OP does not want to find out the hard way).

Comment: @phoog It would be trivial for a large drug operation to make convincing, untampered packages of what look like legitimate medications. The machines aren't *that* expensive or hard to obtain. I would not operate on a "looks legit" basis here.

Comment: "even so, being held in pre-trial custody for several weeks...": Well what I really meant was that there would be a chance of the police not pursuing the matter. But I don't disagree: the prospect of their pursuing it is bad enough no matter how it plays out. Still, it's better to be aware of the possible outcomes and probabilities in making the decision. If it was factory-packed hermetically sealed pills for an actual friend, I would probably go for it in Ireland, but I certainly would not in many other countries, and I wouldn't do it anywhere if the pills were compounded or packaged by hand.

Comment: @ceejayoz good point.  I've carried medicine in the past, but in every case I bought it myself from a pharmacy.  Picking up a seemingly legitimate package from an unknown person would indeed be a different matter.

Comment: I've never flown to Dublin, but you will quite likely be asked at your London check-in whether you are carrying anything for someone else. Even if you really are transporting sugar pills, answering truthfully is still going to lead to a further set of awkward questions. And answering untruthfully would.. not be advisable.

Comment: @ceejayoz The point was that if the packaging looks legitimate, a prosecution would be more likely to fail. So it doesn't matter if we know that legitimate looking sealed packaging could just as well contain drugs, it matters that to a person who is gullible but not literally unbelievably gullible, a sealed medicine packaging is expected to contain what it says on the label.

Comment: There is a rumour that if you carry drugs to Singapore they will only put you in jail for seven days.

Answer (score 24):

Obviously you can carry Homeopathic "medicine" because there's literally nothing in it that does anything, and it isn't medicine.

**However** just because it's described to you as homeopathic medicine doesn't mean it is actually an empty pill. It's not that uncommon for herbal medicines to be misdescribed as homeopathic, and herbal medicines can be basically anything. Just being "natural" doesn't mean it is legal - e.g. magic mushrooms will happily sprout in the wild and cannabis is just a plant.

**And** it's generally a very bad idea to carry something that you can't be sure of for someone else. You have no idea what is in those pills and no way of knowing; the paper from the "physician" will carry no weight at all if there is anything in there that you're not allowed to carry.

**Also**, and perhaps this is me reading to much into your phrasing, but your mention of "all of the packets" suggests that you're being asked to bring a substantial quantity with you. This may open up problems regarding customs and whether you're actually importing in bulk for sale.

Most likely, a pack of pills in your luggage will never get a second glance but that doesn't seem like a risk worth taking. Tell your friend to get his "medicine" from someone in Ireland.

Comment: Your first sentence is not necessarily true. While much homeopatic medication is not really medication and it can be very much diluted, some is medication with real medical powerfull substances and you can never be sure which is harmless and which is real medication.

Comment: @Willeke: The misrepresentation of herbal medicines as homeopathic is what I cover with my second paragraph.

Comment: Following up on that, I remember some years ago where the contents of "traditional Chinese herbal medicines" for skin rashes were properly checked. It turned out that several contained dangerous levels of very-non-herbal steroids! You really don't know what you're getting.

Comment: @JackAidley, having it covered within the text is not enough. You start with a false statement and that will have much more impact than some lines in the middle of a long text.

Comment: @Willeke: I disagree that it is a false statement. Nor do I particularly care what someone who doesn't read an answer takes from it; it's not possible to stuff everything into a single sentence.

Comment: @JackAidley I agree with your views about homeopathy. Still, it's worth noting that if some customs official thinks otherwise, they'll be in a position to make the carrying traveler's life very unpleasant, at least in the short run. While the traveler's it-isn't-medicine argument will likely ultimately prevail, the journey will be neither quick nor cheap. The course of action suggested by JohnnyJanko — just say no — makes more sense.

Comment: @JackAidley Could not a product be illegal that is claimed to do something that it doesn't do?  Meaning, the pills can't be illegal as they are empty pills, but putting them in a medically looking package including false claims could, in some legislations, make this package including false claims and ineffective content illegal?

Comment: @gerrit: I'm not a lawyer in any country, yet alone all of them, so it could be so. However, most countries only regulate claims made on things that are being sold.

Comment: I'm not sure that you need to edit the answer because of this, but there options besides not-really-homeopathic and contains-no-medication.  I've seen homeopathic cough drops that contain lemon and honey as ‘inactive ingredients’ in addition to the homeopathic ‘active ingredient’ that was not really present.  And I once saw a homeopathic rosacea cream with 1X sulfur, that is sulfur diluted to 1/10.  It's certainly not in the spirit of homeopathy to have an ingredient that's diluted so little, but since sulfur is effective against rosacea, that's technically homeopathic while really working.

Comment: @TobyBartels Zicam nasal sprays were an example of this; 1X zinc labeled as homeopathy, taken off the market in the US in 2009 on FDA demands as it was causing anosmia.

Comment: @prosfilaes :  Interesting!  And it appears that the current formulation is an example of the first option; the homeopathic ingredients are a reasonably dilute 4X (so still present in theory but only trace amounts), but the package and advertising tout menthol and eucalyptus, which are listed among the inactive ingredients.  (Who knows how much of those is in there, but at least eucalyptus could help relieve symptoms, although I don't believe the product's claim to shorten the length of the illness for one second.)