# Carrying medicines for my friend to UK

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, international-travel, india, etihad

I will be travelling to UK for my job purpose and one of my friend in UK has asked me to deliver some Ayurvedic medicines for her illness which has prescription and receipt along with it, but I am kind of nervous cause would the immigration people need a letter as well that I am carrying it for his/her patient.

Thank You

Comment: What's the question here?  If you are not a doctor and not a medical exporter you *DO* have to disclose that you're bringing medication to someone.  Doctors will be able to get medications from legitimate sources, if your "friend" is unable to fill this prescription in the UK, you are likely going to be subject to medicine trafficking laws and rules, and are more likely to get those meds seized in Customs.  Have your friend simply use UK pharmacies to get their medications, and not implicate you in a medication smuggling scheme.

Comment: This is nearly a duplicate of [Can I carry someone's homeopathy medicine along to Dublin?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/186183/47309)

Comment: Technically you are importing medicines, so you must follow the UK regulations (and so testing and registration). it is not for personal use (of you), nor a gift (I do not think medicines enter on such category)